# Замена текста через Javascript пр классу

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно автоматическая замена текста по классам, но лично сам никогда  javascript не использовал. У меня есть текстовый элемент, которому я задаю класс "changer". Я бы хотел, что бы он автоматически изменял свой контент (в моем случае это цена) на контент другого текста с классом "source" Т.Е. если я изменю надпись в текстовом элементе с классом "source", это же изменение отобразится вместо записанного раньше текста, у которого класс "changer".

```
<html>
<header>
 </header>
<body>
<h1 class="changer"> Этот текст должен изменится </h1> 
<p class="source"> На этот текст </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Был бы рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

С такими входящими данными можно просто сразу менять значения во всех элементах с нужными классами.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`.source`).forEach($source => {
  document.querySelectorAll(`.changer`).forEach($changer => $changer.innerHTML = $source.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<h1 class="changer"> Этот текст должен изменится </h1>
<p class="source"> На этот текст </p>
```

Приведите более подробный код и что ожидаете от скрипта.